# Using jquery, how do I close a menu by clicking on the body?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

This is my code for opening/expanding the menu

```
$(function(){
    "use strict"
    $('.menu-btn' ).click(function(){
    $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
    })
});
```

It works fine but I am aiming to have it close by clicking on the body (or document) as is normal on most sites but nothing I do seem's to work.

I've tried the below code amongst others but it doesn't work and I don't understand why...

```
$(function(){
    "use strict"
    $('body' ).click(function(){
    $('.responsive-menu').hide()
    })
});
```

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete function you can use.

```
$(".menu-btn").click(function(e){
    if($(".responsive-menu").hasClass("expand")) {
        $(".responsive-menu").removeClass("expand");
    } else {
        $(".responsive-menu").addClass("expand");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("html,body").click(function(){
    if($(".responsive-menu").hasClass("expand")) {
        $(".responsive-menu").removeClass("expand");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back to me with your solution. Adding your code stops the menu from expanding at all, let alone closing by clicking anywhere. Any ideas why?